# Rundeck json job options filtering

Tags: java, jenkins, rundeck

I have a json list output that let's me select multiple values to run the job with. However it's frustrating that if my list is too long then I am unable to search through or filter through the list.Anyone have any idea about this? More specifically does rundeck have any feature to filter across the json list for the job options? Something similar to the one jenkins has https://github.com/imoutsatsos/uno-choice-plugin#rendering-example

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, you can design a granular job cascade options (the first option with some actions in separate JSON files to select on the second option), anyway, that sounds good for improvement, you can suggest it [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).

Comment: Thanks, posted it yesterday https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5973 , waiting for someone to get back on that.